# authentication keys for ssh

Tags: ssh, authentication, keys

I use the following commands on computer A to generate authentication key for ssh from computer A to computer B

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub B:.ssh/authorized_keys2
```

If further I need to generate authentication keys for ssh from Computer C to Computer B, how to prevent overwriting the existing file .ssh/authorized_keys2 on B for A to B?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1):

Upload it under a different name, e.g. `.ssh/newkey`, then ssh in and

```
cat .ssh/newkey >> .ssh/authorized_keys2
```

Or if you would like to be tricky and do it all in one step,

```
ssh user@host "cat - >> .ssh/authorized_keys2" < id_rsa.pub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A#ssh-copy-id B
C#ssh-copy-id B
```

You can pass -i .ssh/some_key.pub to ssh-copy-id if you need to copy a specific pub key. authorized_keys can have multiple key entries, you are not limited to one.

If you do ssh hoping (ssh to a, then from a to b, and from b to c) it might interest you the -A argument to ssh (forwarding keys trough ssh-agent).

Comment: ssh-copy-id is just a shell script, so it makes a good reference as well.  If you have if, you can use `type -t ssh-copy-id` (or maybe which) to see where it is, the look at it with cat/less/vim.